# Erro ao tentar somar tudo através de uma classe em Java

Tags: java, classes-abstratas

Estou fazendo um projeto pequeno sobre controle de despesas,e estou tendo um problema para calcular o total das despesas.
Estou com um classe chamada **Despesa** que é uma classe abstrata,e outras classes chamadas **Transporte**,**Alimentação** e **Diária** irão herdar dela o valor total das despesas e outros dois métodos.
E tenho também uma classe separada chamada **Gerenciador Despesas** com um método que vai passar por parâmetro a classe **Despesa** e pegar o valor total de todas as outras classes,e somar o valor total dentro de uma variável chamada total despesas.
O problema é que quando eu calculo uma das três classes que estão herdando,o valor total da classe **Despesa** irá ir para todas,sendo que eu queria separado,o valor total de cada classe e depois a soma total das três classes.

Classe **Gerenciador Despesas** :

```
public class GerenciadorDespesas {

    private int qtdeAlimentacao;
    private int qtdeTransporte;
    private int qtdeDiaria;
    private double totalAlimentacao;
    private double totalTransporte;
    private double totalDiaria;
    private double totalDespesas;

    public int getQtdeAlimentacao() {
        return qtdeAlimentacao;
    }
    public void setQtdeAlimentacao(int qtdeAlimentacao) {
        this.qtdeAlimentacao = qtdeAlimentacao;
    }
    public int getQtdeTransporte() {
        return qtdeTransporte;
    }
    public void setQtdeTransporte(int qtdeTransporte) {
        this.qtdeTransporte = qtdeTransporte;
    }
    public int getQtdeDiaria() {
        return qtdeDiaria;
    }
    public void setQtdeDiaria(int qtdeDiaria) {
        this.qtdeDiaria = qtdeDiaria;
    }
    public double getTotalAlimentacao() {
        return totalAlimentacao;
    }
    public void setTotalAlimentacao(double totalAlimentacao) {
        this.totalAlimentacao = totalAlimentacao;
    }
    public double getTotalTransporte() {
        return totalTransporte;
    }
    public void setTotalTransporte(double totalTransporte) {
        this.totalTransporte = totalTransporte;
    }
    public double getTotalDiaria() {
        return totalDiaria;
    }
    public void setTotalDiaria(double totalDiaria) {
        this.totalDiaria = totalDiaria;
    }
    public double getTotalDespesas() {
        return totalDespesas;
    }
    public void setTotalDespesas(double totalDespesas) {
        this.totalDespesas = totalDespesas;
    }

    public void analisarDespesas(Despesa despesa) {
    setTotalAlimentacao(despesa.getValorTotal());
    setTotalTransporte(despesa.getValorTotal());
    setTotalDiaria(despesa.getValorTotal());
    setTotalDespesas(getTotalAlimentacao() + getTotalTransporte() +
            getTotalDiaria());

    }


}
```

**Classe Despesa :**

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public abstract class Despesa {

    private String descricao;
    private double valorTotal;

    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao;
    }
    public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }
    public double getValorTotal() {
        return valorTotal;
    }
    public void setValorTotal(double valorTotal) {
        this.valorTotal = valorTotal;
    }

    public void cadastrarDespesa() {
        setValorTotal(0);
        setDescricao(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite a descrição da Despesa : "));
    }


    public abstract void calcularDespesa();
    public abstract void listarDespesa();

}
```

Me desculpem,se a explicação do problema ficou grande demais ou se o código ficou muito grande,por favor,se alguém puder me ajudar irei ficar muito grato.

Comment: Na verdade não dá para responder só com isto. Tem informação de menos. Mas alguma coisa me diz que não deveria estar usando herança.

Comment: As outras três classes somente tem o cadastramento das variáveis e listamento delas e o cálculo nada a mais.Agora sobre a herança,funcionou em meu outro projeto,não sei por que neste não esta funcionando.

Comment: Ah, sim se funciona em um projeto, vai funcionar em todos. Na verdade nem sei o significa funcionou. Quer dizer que compilou? OOP não é isto.

Comment: Quando eu disse isto eu quis dizer que funcionou praticamente com o mesmo código e com uma classe também que era gerenciadora que tinha como função a mesma desta.Se quiser levar pelo lado da ironia e do sarcasmo tudo bem,mas não te insultei de modo algum para vir fazer isto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você falou: "*...Gerenciador Despesas com um método que vai passar por parâmetro a classe Despesa e pegar o valor **total de todas as outras classes**,e somar o valor total dentro de uma variável chamada total despesas. O problema é que quando eu calculo uma das três classes que estão herdando,o valor total da classe Despesa irá ir para todas,sendo que eu queria separado,o valor total de cada classe e depois a soma total das três classes.*"

A solução é criar uma ArrayList estática de Despesas dentro de Despesas
e toda vez que for criada um novo objeto "Despesa" adiciona-lo nessa Array.
Desse modo se salva todos os objetos criados dentro da própria classe

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public abstract class Despesa {

private static ArrayList<Despesa> despesa=new ArrayList<Despesa>();

private String descricao;
private double valorTotal;

public String getDescricao() {
    return descricao;
}

public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
    this.descricao = descricao;
}

public double getValorTotal() {
    return valorTotal;
}

public void setValorTotal(double valorTotal) {
    this.valorTotal = valorTotal;
}
   public void cadastrarDespesa() {
        setValorTotal(0);
        setDescricao(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite a descrição da Despesa : "));
    }


    public abstract void calcularDespesa();
    public abstract void listarDespesa();

    public static ArrayList<Despesa> getDespesa() {
        return despesa;
    }

}
```

Para somar **todas** as Despesas no GerenciamentoDespesas
Se quiser somar só uma, aquele seu primeiro método funciona

PS:Só não entendi pq vc ta atribuindo o mesmo valor a alimentação, tranporte e diaria...Mas vlw

```
public void analisarDespesas(Despesa desp) {
    double ali = 0;
    double trans = 0;
    double dia = 0;
    double total = 0;

    for (Despesa despesa : Despesa.getDespesa()) {
        ali += despesa.getValorTotal();
        trans += despesa.getValorTotal();
        dia += despesa.getValorTotal();
        total += ali + trans + dia;
    }
    setTotalAlimentacao(ali);
    setTotalTransporte(trans);
    setTotalDiaria(dia);
    setTotalDespesas(total);
}
```

Agradeço de der aquele UP na resposta
:)

Comment: Na verdade todos iriam pegar o valor total da classe Despesa,já que nas três classes ambas pegam a variável valor total com getters e setters. Por isso estou atribuindo o mesmo valor.Em outro projeto que fiz uma coisa parecida,funcionou normalmente,mas agora deste jeito neste projeto não funcionou.

Comment: Tentei seu código,mas não foi,mas mesmo assim,obrigado amigo :)